# Using an SN74HC595 as a single-wire state machine

Tags: circuit-design, cmos, shift-register, state-machines, hobbyist

I have an [SN74HC595](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc595.pdf) shift register, and I want to use it to replace a microcontroller to save space and cost, since a microcontroller isn't really needed in my application.

The application is a system that is just a state machine that, whenever it gets a signal, will switch to the next state. Instead of a software-based state machine I want to make it hardware-based. I also want to keep it as simple as possible to keep it small and light, and simple to reproduce.

At start-up I turn on one bit in the shift register, the serialClock and Latch are connected directly to each other, according to the datasheet this will work, but the device output will be one clock behind of the device memory (which is okay in this case).

Then one of the output ports is connected with a resistor to the serial input port so that it loops. I connected the Qh' port to use all 8 states, and because that one displays the storage value and not the output value which avoids having one empty clock.

This all worked; I have tested it with an Arduino Uno, where it would first send in one bit into the serial (through a diode), after which that port was disabled on the Arduino and after which it would use one pin to switch the states every half a second for testing. All of that worked well as expected.

However, I wanted to get rid of the microcontroller as described above, so I altered it so that it automatically turns on one bit on startup, and shifts to the next state whenever it receives a high signal on the clock wire (which it will receive from something like a photodiode, a button, or such).

[image]

Above is the current schematic I made, I used smaller capacitors of 30 μF and 10 μF, but that should still be more than long enough.

The first capacitor is used to generate a short high pulse whenever the device gets power, the second one on the right is to slightly delay the time before the Serialclock and Latch get high enough to trigger the CMOS as high, this is needed, since according to the datasheet the serial data pin needs to be on a very small amount of time (at least) before the serial clock.

So those capacitors, two resistors and two diodes are to turn on one bit when the device turns on. I also added two big resistors to ground because the inputs are CMOS according to the datasheet, and since I pump in power using a diode it should also be able to go back to low again; these also make it so that it only requires a high signal to trigger and return to low by default.

That is basically the entire cirquit as I desired to keep it small and simple.

However, the startup circuit won't start up the first bit in the shift register; I can manually turn them on, and make it rotate/shift, but it just won't turn it on when I power it on while there is the high pulse, and the small delay before the serial clock goes to on.

Is there something I am missing or which I clearly did wrong here? And/or how do I get this to work or make something else, still simple, to automatically turn one bit on at start?

*Note: I know there are really small and technically cheap microprocessors and such; I have these chips laying around and they are easy to use in the way that you can solder them at home. If something is really a lot better suited you can mention it, however, I am a hobbyist and so many ICs are hard to get for me due my mostly relying on local shops, recycled electronics, or having to wait half a year.*

I designed this, and just used the default capacitor size, which is much too large compared to what is needed, making it slower in startup, so the smaller-sized capacitors should be more than slow enough.

I also used buttons to test it and the bounce effect often made the shift register do multiple steps. I tried it on more shift registers and in the same way as people do this on videos with 3 buttons (so the latch and serial clock are both separate buttons).

I guess I can stabilize this with a capacitor bridging the button or going from button to ground, or use something like a diode with a large reverse voltage drop and a transistor to only allow it to send the signal once it is really high. However, this is not the main question since I can probably find a way to debounce the inputs; the main problem is what is described above.

And perhaps just in case, has anyone ever used a shift register as a hardware based simplistic state machine requiring only one input signal, and how did you get it to work properly?

Comment: Are you discharging the capacitors when you power off?
Those capacitors might be holding a charge for a very long time after you remove power, If either capacitor has a charge when you apply power, then it will not work.

Comment: How fast does your supply voltage rise? Can you check these signals with an oscilloscope? Do you know what the Δt/Δv limit in the datasheet means?

Comment: Hi Timmy Brolin, I manually discharge them after shutdown using a wire to short them, but I should indeed add hardware to automatically do so.

Comment: Hi CL, I use a arduino uno as a power supply in my tests, which should be very fast since otherwise the arduino itself likely also would have problems. and no I do not know for sure what the Δt/Δv limit in the datasheet means, I know how voltage affects the maximum frequency, however not about that speciffically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this with a shift register will be fiddly due to the need for setting that valid initial state. It can be done, but reliabilty is a bit of a concern, as you have already found out. You might need one additional active component to make it work.

Easier and more appropriate would be to use a counter. Something like 74HC393 or 74HC161.
A counter will always have a valid initial state automatically. But it also has an asynchronous clear or load input which you can easily use to ensure it starts at a certain state of your choosing.

The output from a counter will however be binary code. You get a sequence of outputs like this:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

And I understand you specifically want a one-hot output sequence, like this?

```
10000000
01000000
00100000
00010000
00001000
00000100
00000010
00000001
```

To do that you can use a decoder/demultiplexer like 74HC238 to convert the binary from the counter to one-hot.

There are also counters with built-in decoder. Such as CD4017.

There are many advantages with using a counter when you need a simple state-machine like this. Besides the startup-issue. For example, with a counter you are no longer limited to a repeating sequence of 8 states. You can set it to any sequence length you want. And you have some options to jump between states in different orders, if you want.

The counters and decoder I mentioned are standard parts available basically anywhere really. On ebay if nothing else.

Comment: I see, I will look into those parts as well. I think I can even use them without using a demultiplexer using some simple transistor, resistor, and diode logic. I'll look if I can find those chips nearby, or similar ones. and perhaps I might even have one laying around which I might somewhere in the past have salvaged. I will also look at a demultiplexer which you referenced to since that might be smaller and lighter than a DIY logic circuit

Comment: Hi Timmy, I found the CD4017 IC counter after searching for counters. none of the ones you mentioned where available here locally. the CD4017 also has a demultiplexer build in an 10 output bits, making it have more ports and reducing space since it will work with one chip. they are also quite cheap. I have ordered a few of those so will switch to a counter like you recommended. you could add those to your post as well. I will however likely still also try to get the shift register working just for the game, but in my project I will use the counter and save a lot of weight that way.

Comment: You are right. CD4017 should work nicely for what you want to do. There are many counters to chose from.

Comment: CD4017 has the benefit of having rather low EMI compared to the 74HC595. The latter produces edges 10-50x faster than the CD4017. If you run the 4017, 4020, 4040, 4022,4024 (all roughly equivalent) from a low voltage supply like 3.3V, it’ll be very docile in regards to EMI. Just make sure that the input rise/fall times are under 1us. If they are not, use a Schmitt buffer like CD4093 or CD40106. Since I literally got every CD4000 family member that exists, I could quickly prototype something for you if you’d like :)

Comment: great that the CD4017 should work.

Comment: I was planning to make Schmitt triggers, or use such a Hex Ic as what you referred to(with scmit triggers in it).  I don't think it will be as hard this time once I receive the material due to working with scmit triggers, and such a counter seeming much more user-friendly for usage as a counter than the shift register. however if you are bored feel free to try something out since the CD4017 will only be in stock in around 2 weeks here. it just needs to change state when it gets a signal, first IR probably, later I want to try things like sound frequency and other methods.

Comment: also in case someone wonders, even though this project is now long ago, 
I did use a CD4017
and it worked very well and super simple and relyable.
I even used the old prototype for something else recently, even though the wires got beaten up over time so was a short cirquit hazard since wire managament already was bad early one, let alone after having it stored for more than a year. but it did work well. also IR range is terrible, luckily normal radio modules also work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a ring counter.
What you want is one that starts from any initial state: "Self-starting standard ring counter" http://www.worldofcomputing.net/digital-electronics/ring-counters.html
All it is, is a NOR gate from all the outputs except the last one, so that it generates a new '1' to put into the register when the previous '1' is all the way at the end.

Also, here is a much simpler Power on reset circuit which I think you were trying to make, just a resistor and capacitor across VCC and GND, (in your case, you would put the resistor to VCC and cap to GND since your SRCLR is active low) https://hardwarebee.com/introduction-to-power-on-reset-circuit/

Comment: That NOR gate method might be smart to use indeed, and quite simple as well by just connecting diodes to the outputs(and resistors to limit current), then merging them all together to get a OR port, and then inverting that. or using a NOR gate IC to save on diodes. in my design I connected SRCLR to + to prevent it from triggering, since the system will work from a stable power source and isn't critical meaning it can be restarted whenever something is wrong, however, I might add something to reset it just before boot.